# Would like to make a table with range of negative/positive and minima/maxima

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

We use a way to find the minina/maxima by splitting the function, calculating the domain,finding the roots of the corresponing polynomials and where is positive or negative the function, and by combining these information, of the derivative of the function, we can find the minima and maxima.
The problem is that I haven't found something to help draw an image like that below, and I do not know tikz which may offer a solution as a drawing. I wonder if there is anything already made, so to not reinvent the wheel.

[image: table]

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found to my earlier post on a same question, that this can be handled with the package tkz-tab. 
for example the above image can be handled with the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[lgt=4,espcl=3]
{ $ x $ /1,
  $ -x^2+4x-1 $ /1, 
  $ (x^2-2x+3)^2 $ /1,
  $ f'(x) $ /1,
  $ f(x) $ /2 }   % make row double in height
%
{ $ -\infty $ , $ 2-\sqrt{3} $ , $ 2+\sqrt{3} $ , $ +\infty $ }
%
\tkzTabLine{ , - ,z,  + ,z, - , }
\tkzTabLine{ , + ,z,  + ,z, + , }
\tkzTabLine{ , - ,z,  + ,z, - , }
\tkzTabVar{     +/ , -/ \text{τ.ε.}  , +/ \text{τ.μ.} , -/}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Hope that this will help others to. Found documentation of tkz-tab, in French, http://altermundus.fr/pages/downloads/TKZdoc-tab.pdf